# Cast to Kodi from "YouTube Cast" android application

Tags: android, youtube, dlna

Android's YouTube application finds my web connected (smart) TV and prompts me to cast a video to it, then the TV opens the YouTube app and plays the video. How can I have the same functionality to Kodi?

I've already enabled the zeroconf/DLNA/etc. services in Kodi and I'm able to stream to it like a normal DLNA device from various Android application but not from the YouTube app itself. I know that I can stream it through Yatse app but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use yatse to send the video to kodi via the 'share' function > 'play on media centre'.